# Mongoose: Need .pre hook to recursively delete children in tree

Tags: node.js, mongodb, recursion, mongoose, tree

I have defined a schema that makes up a **recursive tree structure** in **Mongoose** that works quite well. Each node has an array of children that refer to child nodes in the same tree and schema. The tree can get deep through the recursion in the children.

I would like to use a Mongoose **.pre() middleware hook** to **recursively delete the children (and all their descendants)**, when I delete their parent node with other Mongoose calls.

I tried with variations of the following code, but failed with all kinds of errors - the latest error "baustoff(remove) is not a function at runtime" is documented in comments in the code below.

My questions:

- Which Mongoose call to issue first in the .pre function?
- How to deal with the array of children properly?
- Note: The current deleteMany in my code below gets it at least into the inner part of that function, as the logs show, but might still be wrong....
- How to recursively get the calls to delete all children of children of ... children?
- What to call at the end of .pre where currently the error is raised, to get it working correctly?

Note: Two other Mongoose calls (outside of this model code) to delete parent nodes are supposed to trigger the .pre hook defined above. Code snippets for those two are:

1) await Baustoff.remove ({}); --> this is emptying my db upon start of test, and leads the .pre code into the error "baustoff(remove) is not a function at runtime"

2) Baustoff.findOneAndDelete(req.params.baustoffId) --> could not test this yet, as .pre hook already throws error in 1)

Can someone experienced in Mongoose help me to get this .pre code right? I have certainly one or more errors in that new code part. Thanks much in advance for dealing with my problem!

```
// baustoff.model.js
  const mongoose        = require('mongoose');                    
  const Baustoffe       = require('./../../baustoffe');           // for some enums, irrelevant for BaustoffSchema.pre('remove', )
  const BaumKnotenTypen = require('./../../baumknotentypen');     // for some enums, irrelevant for BaustoffSchema.pre('remove', )             
  const VerzweigungsTypen = require('./../../verzweigungstypen'); // for some enums, irrelevant for BaustoffSchema.pre('remove', )              
  const MaterialEigenschaftSchema  = require('./materialeigenschaft.model.js').model('MaterialEigenschaft').schema 
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  let BaustoffSchema = new Schema  

  ({
    // First some normal properties in my BaustoffSchema schema:
    kurzBezeichnung: { type: String },                                        
    bezeichnung:     { type: String, enum: Object.values(Baustoffe) },       
    baumKnotenTyp:   { type: String, enum: Object.values(BaumKnotenTypen) }, 
    verzweigungsTyp: { type: String, enum: Object.values(VerzweigungsTypen)}, 
    aktiv:           { type: Boolean, default: true},                        
    produkt:         {type: String},
    materialEigenschaften: [MaterialEigenschaftSchema], // some properties as an array to allow variable number of props
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Now an array of references to children that make up a tree structure, as they refer recursively to the model 'Baustoff' 
    kinder:          [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Baustoff' }],      
   },
         {}
   );
   Object.assign(BaustoffSchema.statics, {Baustoffe},{BaumKnotenTypen},{VerzweigungsTypen} ); 
    // Above line is to define some statics, irrelevant for the .pre function
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // PROBLEMATIC PART starts here:
    // Goal: Define a  Mongoose BaustoffSchema.pre() hook that recursively deletes all children further down in the tree, when their parent is deleted

    BaustoffSchema.pre('remove', {query: true}, function(next){
    mongoose.models["Baustoff"].deleteMany({ kinder: this._id }, function(err, baustoff) {
         console.log("In Mongoose pre Hook before if");
         if(baustoff) {
             console.log("In Mongoose pre Hook after if");
             baustoff.remove(); // ERROR is thrown HERE with this variant of the code: baustoff.remove is not a function at runtime !!!!!!!!!!
          });
          next();
      }); // end of .pre hook
  let Baustoff = mongoose.model('Baustoff', BaustoffSchema, 'Baustoffe'); // Model Name, Schema Name, Collection Name in Mongo db
  module.exports = Baustoff; // Baustoff is model name hook
```

Comment: I changed the line that threw the ERROR marked in the code to: 
Baustoff.remove({_id: this._id}).exec(); // Works only with Schema name!!
That leads to an infinite loop in  the .pre hook!
It leads me to believe that a workaround could be to have recursive code that travels through all child nodes, pushes all children to a temporary array, and at the end deletes all the ids in that array. Does anyone have a code snippet for that?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround as indicated in my last comment. I'm not totally happy with it, since it does not use Mongoose .pre middleware as originally desired, but "regular" code to delete all children++ (= descendants) prior to the deletion of a tree node.

If someone knows how to achieve the same using .pre middleware, I would be happy to use that as a preferred solution! I would also appreciate advise whether .pre is the right vehicle for this requirement?

I'm aware that there are more sophisticated solutions to deal with trees, like the materialized path pattern, but be aware that for the time being I'm only looking for solutions that do not change my Mongoose schema.

Here is my initial code for the "regular" deletion of all descendants of a parent node to be deleted in my tree. It uses a temporary stack of _ids to handle the recursion. I'm sure it could be further polished:

```
async function subTreeDelete() {

var descendants = []; // Array to collect all children++, to delete them jointly after the collection phase
var stack = []; // Auxiliary array to recursely collect children that still need to be traversed
const node_id = req.params.baustoffId; // _id of parent node to be deleted, from REST call
var item = await Baustoff.findOne({ _id: node_id }).exec(); // Using await, therefore everything put into an async function
console.log("In Delete children, find parent: ", item); 
stack.push(item); // The parent needs to be traversed first, put it on stack

while (stack.length > 0) {
  var currentnode = stack.pop(); // Get a node from stack, as long as stack isn't empty
  var children = await Baustoff.find({_id: { $in: currentnode.kinder }}).exec(); // Find node's children
  console.log("In Delete children, children: ", children); // Using await, therefore everything put into an async function
  children.forEach(child => {
    descendants.push(child._id); // Push all _ids of direct children on our descendants array that collects the children++
    if (child.kinder.length > 0) {
      stack.push(child); // child node has children still to be traversed, push it on stack
    }
  });
}
console.log("In Delete children: Collected all children of children: ", descendants);
await Baustoff.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: descendants } }).exec(); // Now delete all children++ as collected in descendants
} // /async function

subTreeDelete(); // Call the above async funktion, to delete all children++
// Now we are finally ready to delete the parent node....code for that not included here
```